# Parsley custom dynamic error message

Tags: jquery, validation, error-handling, parsley.js

Parsley (2.8)
I have a custom validator

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('password', {
    validateString: function(value, req, elem) {
        var error = validatePassword(value);
        return error === '';
    },
    messages: {
        en: 'Want my custom message based on input value'
    }
});
```

`validatePassword(value)` return error message according to value, e.g. special character is missing. So how I can access value or input element inside error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle, I found a solution. We can't specify callback with arguments to create a dynamic error message but we can add an error message in validation callback where we have access to input value and element as well.

> `window.Parsley.addMessage(lenguage, validatorName, customErrorMessage)`
>
> `window.Parsley.addMessage('en', 'password', 'Missing special character')`

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('password', {
    validateString: function(value, req, elem) {
        // We can add dynamic error message here.
        // window.Parsley.addMessage(lenguage, validatorName, customErrorMessage);
        var error = validatePassword(value); // validatePassword() returns error message if there are any validation errors otherwise empty string.
        window.Parsley.addMessage('en', 'password',error);
        return error === '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the way to return a "dynamic" error message is by returning a failed promise from your `validateString` method. [This example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/ajax.html) uses this technique.